# IGMP Request with Indy Multicast Client

Tags: delphi, indy, multicast, igmp

I'm writing an app which uses the Indy Multicast Client from Delphi XE5.

When I set `Active:=true`, I can see the Multicast Group Request in Wireshark and my managed switch forwards multicasts to my app. But this request is only sent on startup. After a few minutes, IGMP snooping on the switch runs into a timeout and kicks my app from its multicast table. I also have hardware units connected to my local network which send these group reports periodically for themselves and so they stay in the switches multicast list.

How can I sent group requests periodically with Indy?

I tried:

```
UDPMulticastClient.Bindings[0].AddMulticastMembership(MulticastGroup);
```

But that throws me an exception ("Error #10022, Invalid Argument").

Comment: Which `IPVersion` are you using - IPv4 or IPv6?  Which OS and version is your client running on?  Which IGMP version is being used by the underlying socket?

Comment: Using IPv4 on Win 7 x64 (Dev machine) and in future on Win Server 2012 (production), IGMP-Version should be v2.
My hardware module on the other end sends a simple IGMPv2 "Membership Report" (Type 0x16) periodically to the network and my switch holds this device in its multicast tables.